# problem in adding image view between two vertical linear layout placed side by side in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having problem in adding `ImageView` between two vertical linear layout placed side by side in android studio as shown in image. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpJCe.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
      tools:visibility="visible" >
      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView11"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="106dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="304dp"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/download" />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   **<LinearLayout**
   android:layout_width="202dp"
   android:layout_height="598dp"
   android:background="#F4F6F2"
   android:backgroundTint="#F0F4EC"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp" />
   **<LinearLayout**
   android:layout_width="206dp"
   android:layout_height="601dp"
   android:background="#FEFEFF"
   android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="204dp"
   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp">
   </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of a nested view group as constraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#F4F6F2"
    android:backgroundTint="#F0F4EC"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FEFEFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="304dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge_circle" />
```

The above changes are working as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code and see if it works:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#F4F6F2"
    android:backgroundTint="#F0F4EC"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FEFEFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


</LinearLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/download" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If it is working then accept the answer for the clarification. @sam

Comment: sorry to say but it's not working as if I try to move the image slightly upward or downward it shows either the left side or right side also when I try to insert the button same problem goes on.

Comment: Make sure you are not adding the image in the LinearLayout when you move the image.